# Setup OAuth2 in Lumen

Tags: php, oauth, oauth-2.0, lumen

I followed [this](http://esbenp.github.io/2015/05/26/lumen-web-api-oauth-2-authentication/) article written to setup OAuth2 for my API that I'm writing in `Lumen`. I finished setting it up and I implemented the client so that I could test that it works. I haven't been able to get it to work. When I click the 'Login to API' button, it sends a POST to `http://myserver.com/login` and it never finishes. It hangs here and I get no exceptions or errors of any kind. Also, when it hangs like that I cannot just refresh the page. I have to serve it on another port, if that's a clue as to what's happening. I output a bunch of log messages and I've narrowed the trouble down to this:

```
$guzzleResponse = $client->post(sprintf('%s/oauth/access-token', $config->get('app.url')), [
            'body' => $data
        ]);
```

I checked the parameters and they look good. `$client` is a `GuzzleHttp` Client. The post method inside looks like this:

```
public function post($url = null, array $options = [])
{
    return $this->send($this->createRequest('POST', $url, $options));
}
```

I think I may have to enable cookies in Lumen. Where would I go to find that out? Does anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: Could you not pull in Laravel's Socialite instead of rolling your own?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, Socailite is for a client to authenticate from a provider, like Github. In my case, I'm the provider and I need to have an OAuth2 server that interacts with a client that others are developing.

Answer (score 2):

To enable cookie, you can do this in .env file -

```
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
```

Then run `composer update` command.

Answer (score 0):

Had you check your .env?.. please add AUTH_MODEL=App\Auth\User if that no there.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Guzzle doesnot work with port eg localhost:8888. If you are runnnig your server on some port change it to default 80  and guzzle will work